# array_diff() is not working

Tags: php, arrays

```
$intersect    =    array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($intersect);
```

I have two arrays and I used array_diff

```
$array1 =Array ( [0] => Fees 1 [1] => Fees 2 [2] => Fees 24 [3] => Fees 99 )
$array2 = Array ( [0] => Fees 1 [1] => Fees 24 [2] => Fees 2 )
```

And used:

```
array_diff($array1,$array2);
```

I need ans of:

```
Array ( [0] => Fees 99 )
```

But I got:

```
Array ( [1] => Fees 2 [3] => Fees 99 )
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us your **full** and real code

Comment: do a `var_dump()` on `$array1` & `$array2` to check if the `Fees 2` are the same, could be a whitespace issue.

Comment: Yes as @Sean said it could be a whitespace issue

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably not working, because of spaces. So to get rid of these spaces i used [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) combined with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to delete those spaces.

Also at the end i used [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex the array starting with 0.

```
print_r(array_values(array_diff(array_map("trim", $array1), array_map("trim", $array2))));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Fees 99 )
```

Also to see the difference and the different amout of spaces use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) Like this:

```
var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
```

And then you should be able to see the difference (Example output):

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Fees 1 "
  [1]=>
  string(8) " Fees 2 "
       //^ See here
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Fees 24 "
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Fees 99 "
}

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Fees 1 "
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Fees 24 "
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Fees 2 "
       //^ See here
}
```